Access elementor swiper instance to attach custom navigation buttons
I need to access to a swiper instance that is created from elementor in side may page template. I need to attach two next/prev navigation buttons so I can be able to scroll the images using the two custom buttons I've created. At the moment I've this code but seems not work when I go into preview mode or if I load the page normally
<div id="navigation-wrapper">
<span class="prev">PREV</span>
    <span class="nav-spacer"></span>
<span class="next">NEXT</span>
</div>

    setTimeout(function(){
const swiper = new Swiper(".elementor-element-1d8d7e9 .swiper", {
  // Optional parameters
  slidesPerView:3,
  //centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  height: 550,
  //autoHeight: true,
  //initialSlide: 1
 // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".next",
    prevEl: ".prev",
  },
  on: {
    init: function () {
        console.log(jQuery('.swiper-slide-next .swiper-slide-image').width())
      jQuery('#navigation-wrapper').css({
          'width': jQuery('.swiper-slide-next .swiper-slide-image').width()+'px'
          })
    },
  },

});

}, 1000)

#navigation-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
.prev {
    /* other style rules here for navigation arrow */
}
.next {
   /* other style rules here for navigation arrow */    
}

Is there a way to force the embedded elementor slider to use custom navigation buttons instead of the default arrows that can be activated from the carousel widget options?
At the moment in console I will get an error message ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
